# Need to shorten Grok Pattern

Tags: logstash, logstash-grok

I am using a Grok pattern to parse firewall logs and the Grok pattern works when using [Grok Debugger](http://grokdebug.herokuapp.com/). The log data changes and I've created patterns to match each change. My issue is that ELK is producing multiple duplicate fields for the parsed data. I am sure there is a way to shorten my grok pattern but at this point I am not able to figure out how. So any assistance would be awesome. See below for examples:

Sample logs:

```
Nov 15 12:18:31 removed_ip 2017:11:15-12:18:31 sophie ulogd[23109]: id="2001" severity="info" sys="SecureNet" sub="packetfilter" name="Packet dropped" action="drop" fwrule="60001" initf="eth3" srcmac="removed_mac" dstmac="removed_mac" srcip="removed_ip" dstip="removed_ip" proto="6" length="40" tos="0x00" prec="0x00" ttl="247" srcport="58261" dstport="5315" tcpflags="SYN"
Nov 15 12:33:01 removed_ip 2017:11:15-12:33:01 sophie ulogd[23109]: id="2001" severity="info" sys="SecureNet" sub="packetfilter" name="Packet dropped" action="drop" fwrule="60003" outitf="wlan1" srcmac="removed_mac" srcip="removed_ip" dstip="removed_ip" proto="6" length="40" tos="0x00" prec="0x00" ttl="64" srcport="443" dstport="49824" tcpflags="RST" 
Nov 15 12:20:29 removed_ip 2017:11:15-12:20:29 sophie httpproxy[6835]: id="0001" severity="info" sys="SecureWeb" sub="http" name="http access" action="pass" method="GET" srcip="removed_ip" dstip="removed_ip" user="" group="" ad_domain="" statuscode="200" cached="0" profile="REF_DefaultHTTPProfile (Default Web Filter Profile)" filteraction="REF_DefaultHTTPCFFAction (Default content filter action)" size="371" request="0xd3a9ac00" url="http://removed_ip/icingaweb2/monitoring/tactical?view=compact" referer="http://removed_ip/icingaweb2/dashboard" error="" authtime="0" dnstime="218" cattime="0" avscantime="2584" fullreqtime="15393756" device="0" auth="0" ua="Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/61.0.3163.100 Safari/537.36" exceptions="" overridecategory="1" overridereputation="1" category="105" reputation="trusted" categoryname="Business" country="United States" sandbox="-" content-type="text/xml"
Nov 15 12:30:33 removed_ip 2017:11:15-12:30:33 sophie httpproxy[6835]: id="0001" severity="info" sys="SecureWeb" sub="http" name="http access" action="pass" method="CONNECT" srcip="removed_ip" dstip="removed_ip" user="" group="" ad_domain="" statuscode="200" cached="0" profile="REF_DefaultHTTPProfile (Default Web Filter Profile)" filteraction="REF_DefaultHTTPCFFAction (Default content filter action)" size="11571" request="0xd21c1800" url="https://www.google.com/" referer="" error="" authtime="0" dnstime="1" cattime="97" avscantime="0" fullreqtime="361956728" device="0" auth="0" ua="" exceptions="" category="145" reputation="neutral" categoryname="Search Engines" country="United States" application="google" app-id="182"
```

Sample Grok Pattern:

```
filter { 
if [type] == "utm"{
grok {
  match => {"message" => "%{SYSLOGTIMESTAMP:timestamp} %{HOSTNAME:hostname} (?<timestamp>%{YEAR}:%{MONTHNUM}:%{MONTHDAY}-%{HOUR}:%{MINUTE}:%{SECOND}) %{HOSTNAME:logsource} %{WORD:program}\[%{INT:pid}]\: id=\"%{INT:id}\" severity=\"%{WORD:severity}\" sys=\"%{WORD:sys}\" sub=\"%{WORD:sub}\" name=\"%{DATA:name}\" action=\"%{DATA:action}\" fwrule=\"%{INT:fwrule}\" initf=\"%{NOTSPACE:initf}\" outitf=\"%{NOTSPACE:outitf}\" mark=\"%{WORD:mark}\" app=\"%{WORD:app}\" srcmac=\"%{MAC:srcmac}\" dstmac=\"%{MAC:dstmac}\" srcip=\"%{IPV4:source_ip}\" dstip=\"%{IPV4:destination_ip}\" proto=\"%{WORD:protocol}\" length=\"%{INT:length}\" tos=\"%{DATA:tos}\" prec=\"%{DATA:prec}\" ttl=\"%{INT:ttl}\" srcport=\"%{INT:srcport}\" dstport=\"%{INT:dstport}\" "}
}
grok {
  match => { "message" => "%{SYSLOGTIMESTAMP:timestamp} %{HOSTNAME:hostname} (?<timestamp>%{YEAR}:%{MONTHNUM}:%{MONTHDAY}-%{HOUR}:%{MINUTE}:%{SECOND}) %{HOSTNAME:logsource} %{WORD:program}\[%{INT:pid}]\: id=\"%{INT:id}\" severity=\"%{WORD:severity}\" sys=\"%{WORD:sys}\" sub=\"%{WORD:sub}\" name=\"%{DATA:name}\" action=\"%{DATA:action}\" fwrule=\"%{INT:fwrule}\" initf=\"%{NOTSPACE:initf}\" outitf=\"%{NOTSPACE:outitf}\" srcmac=\"%{MAC:srcmac}\" dstmac=\"%{MAC:dstmac}\" srcip=\"%{IPV4:source_ip}\" dstip=\"%{IPV4:destination_ip}\" proto=\"%{WORD:protocol}\" length=\"%{INT:length}\" tos=\"%{DATA:tos}\" prec=\"%{DATA:prec}\" ttl=\"%{INT:ttl}\" srcport=\"%{INT:srcport}\" dstport=\"%{INT:dstport}\" "}
 }
grok {
  match => { "message" => "%{SYSLOGTIMESTAMP:timestamp} %{HOSTNAME:hostname} (?<timestamp>%{YEAR}:%{MONTHNUM}:%{MONTHDAY}-%{HOUR}:%{MINUTE}:%{SECOND}) %{HOSTNAME:logsource} %{WORD:program}\[%{INT:pid}]\: id=\"%{INT:id}\" severity=\"%{WORD:severity}\" sys=\"%{WORD:sys}\" sub=\"%{WORD:sub}\" name=\"%{DATA:name}\" action=\"%{DATA:action}\" fwrule=\"%{INT:fwrule}\" initf=\"%{NOTSPACE:initf}\" outitf=\"%{NOTSPACE:outitf}\" srcmac=\"%{MAC:srcmac}\" srcip=\"%{IPV4:source_ip}\" dstip=\"%{IPV4:destination_ip}\" proto=\"%{WORD:protocol}\" length=\"%{INT:length}\" tos=\"%{DATA:tos}\" prec=\"%{DATA:prec}\" ttl=\"%{INT:ttl}\" srcport=\"%{INT:srcport}\" dstport=\"%{INT:dstport}\" "}
 }
grok {
  match => {"message" => "%{SYSLOGTIMESTAMP:timestamp} %{HOSTNAME:hostname} (?<timestamp>%{YEAR}:%{MONTHNUM}:%{MONTHDAY}-%{HOUR}:%{MINUTE}:%{SECOND}) %{HOSTNAME:logsource} %{WORD:program}\[%{INT:pid}]\: id=\"%{INT:id}\" severity=\"%{WORD:severity}\" sys=\"%{WORD:sys}\" sub=\"%{WORD:sub}\" name=\"%{DATA:name}\" action=\"%{DATA:action}\" fwrule=\"%{INT:fwrule}\" outitf=\"%{NOTSPACE:outitf}\" mark=\"%{DATA:mark}\" app=\"%{DATA:app}\" srcmac=\"%{MAC:srcmac}\" srcip=\"%{IPV4:source_ip}\" dstip=\"%{IPV4:destination_ip}\" proto=\"%{WORD:protocol}\" length=\"%{INT:length}\" tos=\"%{DATA:tos}\" prec=\"%{DATA:prec}\" ttl=\"%{INT:ttl}\" srcport=\"%{INT:srcport}\" dstport=\"%{INT:dstport}\" "}
 }
grok {
  match => { "message" => "%{SYSLOGTIMESTAMP:timestamp} %{HOSTNAME:hostname} (?<timestamp>%{YEAR}:%{MONTHNUM}:%{MONTHDAY}-%{HOUR}:%{MINUTE}:%{SECOND}) %{HOSTNAME:logsource} %{WORD:program}\[%{INT:pid}]\: id=\"%{INT:id}\" severity=\"%{WORD:severity}\" sys=\"%{WORD:sys}\" sub=\"%{WORD:sub}\" name=\"%{DATA:name}\" action=\"%{DATA:action}\" fwrule=\"%{INT:fwrule}\" initf=\"%{NOTSPACE:initf}\" srcmac=\"%{MAC:srcmac}\" dstmac=\"%{MAC:dstmac}\" srcip=\"%{IPV4:source_ip}\" dstip=\"%{IPV4:destination_ip}\" proto=\"%{WORD:protocol}\" length=\"%{INT:length}\" tos=\"%{DATA:tos}\" prec=\"%{DATA:prec}\" ttl=\"%{INT:ttl}\" srcport=\"%{INT:srcport}\" dstport=\"%{INT:dstport}\" "}
 }
grok {
  match => { "message" => "%{SYSLOGTIMESTAMP:timestamp} %{HOSTNAME:hostname} (?<timestamp>%{YEAR}:%{MONTHNUM}:%{MONTHDAY}-%{HOUR}:%{MINUTE}:%{SECOND}) %{HOSTNAME:logsource} %{WORD:program}\[%{INT:pid}]\: id=\"%{INT:id}\" severity=\"%{WORD:severity}\" sys=\"%{WORD:sys}\" sub=\"%{WORD:sub}\" name=\"%{DATA:name}\" action=\"%{DATA:action}\" fwrule=\"%{INT:fwrule}\" outitf=\"%{NOTSPACE:outitf}\" srcmac=\"%{MAC:srcmac}\" srcip=\"%{IPV4:source_ip}\" dstip=\"%{IPV4:destination_ip}\" proto=\"%{WORD:protocol}\" length=\"%{INT:length}\" tos=\"%{DATA:tos}\" prec=\"%{DATA:prec}\" ttl=\"%{INT:ttl}\" srcport=\"%{INT:srcport}\" dstport=\"%{INT:dstport}\" "}
 }
grok {
  match => {"message" => "%{SYSLOGTIMESTAMP:timestamp} %{HOSTNAME:hostname} (?<timestamp>%{YEAR}:%{MONTHNUM}:%{MONTHDAY}-%{HOUR}:%{MINUTE}:%{SECOND}) %{HOSTNAME:logsource} %{WORD:program}\[%{INT:pid}]\: id=\"%{INT:id}\" severity=\"%{WORD:severity}\" sys=\"%{WORD:sys}\" sub=\"%{WORD:sub}\" name=\"%{DATA:name}\" action=\"%{DATA:action}\" fwrule=\"%{INT:fwrule}\" initf=\"%{NOTSPACE:initf}\" outitf=\"%{NOTSPACE:outitf}\" srcmac=\"%{MAC:srcmac}\" dstmac=\"%{MAC:dstmac}\" srcip=\"%{IPV4:source_ip}\" dstip=\"%{IPV4:destination_ip}\" proto=\"%{WORD:protocol}\" length=\"%{INT:length}\" tos=\"%{DATA:tos}\" prec=\"%{DATA:prec}\" ttl=\"%{INT:ttl}\" srcport=\"%{INT:srcport}\" dstport=\"%{INT:dstport}\" tcpflags=\"%{DATA:tcpflags}\" \"(,)\" "}
}
grok {
 match => {"message" => "%{SYSLOGTIMESTAMP:timestamp} %{HOSTNAME:hostname} (?<timestamp>%{YEAR}:%{MONTHNUM}:%{MONTHDAY}-%{HOUR}:%{MINUTE}:%{SECOND}) %{HOSTNAME:logsource} %{WORD:program}\[%{INT:pid}]\: id=\"%{INT:id}\" severity=\"%{WORD:severity}\" sys=\"%{WORD:sys}\" sub=\"%{WORD:sub}\" name=\"%{DATA:name}\" action=\"%{DATA:action}\" fwrule=\"%{INT:fwrule}\" initf=\"%{NOTSPACE:initf}\" srcmac=\"%{MAC:srcmac}\" dstmac=\"%{MAC:dstmac}\" srcip=\"%{IPV4:source_ip}\" dstip=\"%{IPV4:destination_ip}\" proto=\"%{WORD:protocol}\" length=\"%{INT:length}\" tos=\"%{DATA:tos}\" prec=\"%{DATA:prec}\" ttl=\"%{INT:ttl}\" srcport=\"%{INT:srcport}\" dstport=\"%{INT:dstport}\" tcpflags=\"%{DATA:tcpflags}\" "}
}
grok {
 match => {"message" => "%{SYSLOGTIMESTAMP:timestamp} %{HOSTNAME:hostname} (?<timestamp>%{YEAR}:%{MONTHNUM}:%{MONTHDAY}-%{HOUR}:%{MINUTE}:%{SECOND}) %{HOSTNAME:logsource} %{WORD:program}\[%{INT:pid}]\: id=\"%{INT:id}\" severity=\"%{WORD:severity}\" sys=\"%{WORD:sys}\" sub=\"%{WORD:sub}\" name=\"%{DATA:name}\" action=\"%{DATA:action}\" fwrule=\"%{INT:fwrule}\" outitf=\"%{NOTSPACE:outitf}\" srcmac=\"%{MAC:srcmac}\" srcip=\"%{IPV4:source_ip}\" dstip=\"%{IPV4:destination_ip}\" proto=\"%{WORD:protocol}\" length=\"%{INT:length}\" tos=\"%{DATA:tos}\" prec=\"%{DATA:prec}\" ttl=\"%{INT:ttl}\" srcport=\"%{INT:srcport}\" dstport=\"%{INT:dstport}\" tcpflags=\"%{DATA:tcpflags}\" "}
}
grok {
 match => {"message" => "%{SYSLOGTIMESTAMP:timestamp} %{HOSTNAME:hostname} (?<timestamp>%{YEAR}:%{MONTHNUM}:%{MONTHDAY}-%{HOUR}:%{MINUTE}:%{SECOND}) %{HOSTNAME:logsource} %{WORD:program}\[%{INT:pid}]\: id=\"%{INT:id}\" severity=\"%{WORD:severity}\" sys=\"%{WORD:sys}\" sub=\"%{WORD:sub}\" name=\"%{DATA:name}\" action=\"%{DATA:action}\" fwrule=\"%{INT:fwrule}\" initf=\"%{NOTSPACE:initf}\" outitf=\"%{NOTSPACE:outitf}\" mark=\"%{WORD:mark}\" app=\"%{WORD:app}\" srcmac=\"%{MAC:srcmac}\" dstmac=\"%{MAC:dstmac}\" srcip=\"%{IPV4:source_ip}\" dstip=\"%{IPV4:destination_ip}\" proto=\"%{WORD:protocol}\" length=\"%{INT:length}\" tos=\"%{DATA:tos}\" prec=\"%{DATA:prec}\" ttl=\"%{INT:ttl}\" srcport=\"%{INT:srcport}\" dstport=\"%{INT:dstport}\" tcpflags=\"%{DATA:tcpflags}\" "}
}
grok {
 match => {"message" => "%{SYSLOGTIMESTAMP:timestamp} %{HOSTNAME:hostname} (?<timestamp>%{YEAR}:%{MONTHNUM}:%{MONTHDAY}-%{HOUR}:%{MINUTE}:%{SECOND}) %{HOSTNAME:logsource} %{WORD:program}\[%{INT:pid}]\: id=\"%{INT:id}\" severity=\"%{WORD:severity}\" sys=\"%{WORD:sys}\" sub=\"%{WORD:sub}\" name=\"%{DATA:name}\" action=\"%{DATA:action}\" fwrule=\"%{INT:fwrule}\" initf=\"%{NOTSPACE:initf}\" outitf=\"%{NOTSPACE:outitf}\" mark=\"%{WORD:mark}\" srcmac=\"%{MAC:srcmac}\" dstmac=\"%{MAC:dstmac}\" srcip=\"%{IPV4:source_ip}\" dstip=\"%{IPV4:destination_ip}\" proto=\"%{WORD:protocol}\" length=\"%{INT:length}\" tos=\"%{DATA:tos}\" prec=\"%{DATA:prec}\" ttl=\"%{INT:ttl}\" srcport=\"%{INT:srcport}\" dstport=\"%{INT:dstport}\" tcpflags=\"%{DATA:tcpflags}\" "}
}
}
if "httpproxy" in [message]{
grok {
match => {"message" => "%{SYSLOGTIMESTAMP:timestamp} %{HOSTNAME:hostname} (?<timestamp>%{YEAR}:%{MONTHNUM}:%{MONTHDAY}-%{HOUR}:%{MINUTE}:%{SECOND}) %{HOSTNAME:logsource} %{WORD:program}\[%{INT:pid}]\: id=\"%{INT:id}\" severity=\"%{WORD:severity}\" sys=\"%{WORD:sys}\" sub=\"%{WORD:sub}\" name=\"%{DATA:name}\" action=\"%{DATA:action}\" method=\"%{WORD:method}\" srcip=\"%{IPV4:source_ip}\" dstip=\"%{IPV4:destination_ip}\" user=\"%{DATA:user}\" group=\"%{DATA:group}\" ad_domain=\"%{DATA:ad_domain}\" statuscode=\"%{INT:statuscode}\" cached=\"%{INT:cached}\" profile=\"%{DATA:profile}\" filteraction=\"%{DATA:filteraction}\" size=\"%{INT:size}\" request=\"%{BASE16FLOAT:request}\" url=\"%{URI:url}\" referer=\"%{DATA:referer}\" error=\"%{DATA:error}\" authtime=\"%{INT:authtime}\" dnstime=\"%{INT:dnstime}\" cattime=\"%{INT:cattime}\" avscantime=\"%{INT:avscantime}\" fullreqtime=\"%{INT:fullreqtime}\" device=\"%{INT:device}\" auth=\"%{INT:auth}\" ua=\"%{DATA:ua}\" exceptions=\"%{DATA:exceptions}\" category=\"%{INT:category}\" reputation=\"%{WORD:reputation}\" categoryname=\"%{DATA:categoryname}\" country=\"%{DATA:country}\" application=\"%{WORD:application}\" app-id=\"%{INT:app-id}\" sandbox=\"%{DATA:sandbox}\" content-type=\"%{DATA:content-type}\" "}
}
grok {
match => {"message" => "%{SYSLOGTIMESTAMP:timestamp} %{HOSTNAME:hostname} (?<timestamp>%{YEAR}:%{MONTHNUM}:%{MONTHDAY}-%{HOUR}:%{MINUTE}:%{SECOND}) %{HOSTNAME:logsource} %{WORD:program}\[%{INT:pid}]\: id=\"%{INT:id}\" severity=\"%{WORD:severity}\" sys=\"%{WORD:sys}\" sub=\"%{WORD:sub}\" name=\"%{DATA:name}\" action=\"%{DATA:action}\" method=\"%{WORD:method}\" srcip=\"%{IPV4:source_ip}\" dstip=\"%{IPV4:destination_ip}\" user=\"%{DATA:user}\" group=\"%{DATA:group}\" ad_domain=\"%{DATA:ad_domain}\" statuscode=\"%{INT:statuscode}\" cached=\"%{INT:cached}\" profile=\"%{DATA:profile}\" filteraction=\"%{DATA:filteraction}\" size=\"%{INT:size}\" request=\"%{BASE16FLOAT:request}\" url=\"%{URI:url}\" referer=\"%{DATA:referer}\" error=\"%{DATA:error}\" authtime=\"%{INT:authtime}\" dnstime=\"%{INT:dnstime}\" cattime=\"%{INT:cattime}\" avscantime=\"%{INT:avscantime}\" fullreqtime=\"%{INT:fullreqtime}\" device=\"%{INT:device}\" auth=\"%{INT:auth}\" ua=\"%{DATA:ua}\" exceptions=\"%{DATA:exceptions}\" overridecategory=\"%{INT:overridecategory}\" overridereputation=\"%{INT:overridereputation}\" category=\"%{INT:category}\" reputation=\"%{WORD:reputation}\" categoryname=\"%{DATA:categoryname}\" country=\"%{DATA:country}\" sandbox=\"%{DATA:sandbox}\" content-type=\"%{DATA:content-type}\" "}
}
grok {
 match => {"message" => "%{SYSLOGTIMESTAMP:timestamp} %{HOSTNAME:hostname} (?<timestamp>%{YEAR}:%{MONTHNUM}:%{MONTHDAY}-%{HOUR}:%{MINUTE}:%{SECOND}) %{HOSTNAME:logsource} %{WORD:program}\[%{INT:pid}]\: id=\"%{INT:id}\" severity=\"%{WORD:severity}\" sys=\"%{WORD:sys}\" sub=\"%{WORD:sub}\" name=\"%{DATA:name}\" action=\"%{DATA:action}\" method=\"%{WORD:method}\" srcip=\"%{IPV4:source_ip}\" dstip=\"%{IPV4:destination_ip}\" user=\"%{DATA:user}\" group=\"%{DATA:group}\" ad_domain=\"%{DATA:ad_domain}\" statuscode=\"%{INT:statuscode}\" cached=\"%{INT:cached}\" profile=\"%{DATA:profile}\" filteraction=\"%{DATA:filteraction}\" size=\"%{INT:size}\" request=\"%{BASE16FLOAT:request}\" url=\"%{URI:url}\" referer=\"%{DATA:referer}\" error=\"%{DATA:error}\" authtime=\"%{INT:authtime}\" dnstime=\"%{INT:dnstime}\" cattime=\"%{INT:cattime}\" avscantime=\"%{INT:avscantime}\" fullreqtime=\"%{INT:fullreqtime}\" device=\"%{INT:device}\" auth=\"%{INT:auth}\" ua=\"%{DATA:ua}\" exceptions=\"%{DATA:exceptions}\" category=\"%{INT:category}\" reputation=\"%{WORD:reputation}\" categoryname=\"%{DATA:categoryname}\" sandbox=\"%{DATA:sandbox}\" content-type=\"%{DATA:content-type}\" "}
}
grok {
match => {"message" => "%{SYSLOGTIMESTAMP:timestamp} %{HOSTNAME:hostname} (?<timestamp>%{YEAR}:%{MONTHNUM}:%{MONTHDAY}-%{HOUR}:%{MINUTE}:%{SECOND}) %{HOSTNAME:logsource} %{WORD:program}\[%{INT:pid}]\: id=\"%{INT:id}\" severity=\"%{WORD:severity}\" sys=\"%{WORD:sys}\" sub=\"%{WORD:sub}\" name=\"%{DATA:name}\" action=\"%{DATA:action}\" method=\"%{WORD:method}\" srcip=\"%{IPV4:source_ip}\" dstip=\"%{IPV4:destination_ip}\" user=\"%{DATA:user}\" group=\"%{DATA:group}\" ad_domain=\"%{DATA:ad_domain}\" statuscode=\"%{INT:statuscode}\" cached=\"%{INT:cached}\" profile=\"%{DATA:profile}\" filteraction=\"%{DATA:filteraction}\" size=\"%{INT:size}\" request=\"%{BASE16FLOAT:request}\" url=\"%{URI:url}\" referer=\"%{DATA:referer}\" error=\"%{DATA:error}\" authtime=\"%{INT:authtime}\" dnstime=\"%{INT:dnstime}\" cattime=\"%{INT:cattime}\" avscantime=\"%{INT:avscantime}\" fullreqtime=\"%{INT:fullreqtime}\" device=\"%{INT:device}\" auth=\"%{INT:auth}\" ua=\"%{DATA:ua}\" exceptions=\"%{DATA:exceptions}\" "}
}
grok {
match => {"message" => "%{SYSLOGTIMESTAMP:timestamp} %{HOSTNAME:hostname} (?<timestamp>%{YEAR}:%{MONTHNUM}:%{MONTHDAY}-%{HOUR}:%{MINUTE}:%{SECOND}) %{HOSTNAME:logsource} %{WORD:program}\[%{INT:pid}]\: id=\"%{INT:id}\" severity=\"%{WORD:severity}\" sys=\"%{WORD:sys}\" sub=\"%{WORD:sub}\" name=\"%{DATA:name}\" action=\"%{DATA:action}\" method=\"%{WORD:method}\" srcip=\"%{IPV4:source_ip}\" dstip=\"%{IPV4:destination_ip}\" user=\"%{DATA:user}\" group=\"%{DATA:group}\" ad_domain=\"%{DATA:ad_domain}\" statuscode=\"%{INT:statuscode}\" cached=\"%{INT:cached}\" profile=\"%{DATA:profile}\" filteraction=\"%{DATA:filteraction}\" size=\"%{INT:size}\" request=\"%{BASE16FLOAT:request}\" url=\"%{URI:url}\" referer=\"%{DATA:referer}\" error=\"%{DATA:error}\" authtime=\"%{INT:authtime}\" dnstime=\"%{INT:dnstime}\" cattime=\"%{INT:cattime}\" avscantime=\"%{INT:avscantime}\" fullreqtime=\"%{INT:fullreqtime}\" device=\"%{INT:device}\" auth=\"%{INT:auth}\" ua=\"%{DATA:ua}\" exceptions=\"%{DATA:exceptions}\" overridecategory=\"%{INT:overridecategory}\" overridereputation=\"%{INT:overridereputation}\" country=\"%{DATA:country}\" "}
}
grok {
match => {"message" => "%{SYSLOGTIMESTAMP:timestamp} %{HOSTNAME:hostname} (?<timestamp>%{YEAR}:%{MONTHNUM}:%{MONTHDAY}-%{HOUR}:%{MINUTE}:%{SECOND}) %{HOSTNAME:logsource} %{WORD:program}\[%{INT:pid}]\: id=\"%{INT:id}\" severity=\"%{WORD:severity}\" sys=\"%{WORD:sys}\" sub=\"%{WORD:sub}\" name=\"%{DATA:name}\" action=\"%{DATA:action}\" method=\"%{WORD:method}\" srcip=\"%{IPV4:source_ip}\" dstip=\"%{IPV4:destination_ip}\" user=\"%{DATA:user}\" group=\"%{DATA:group}\" ad_domain=\"%{DATA:ad_domain}\" statuscode=\"%{INT:statuscode}\" cached=\"%{INT:cached}\" profile=\"%{DATA:profile}\" filteraction=\"%{DATA:filteraction}\" size=\"%{INT:size}\" request=\"%{BASE16FLOAT:request}\" url=\"%{URI:url}\" referer=\"%{DATA:referer}\" error=\"%{DATA:error}\" authtime=\"%{INT:authtime}\" dnstime=\"%{INT:dnstime}\" cattime=\"%{INT:cattime}\" avscantime=\"%{INT:avscantime}\" fullreqtime=\"%{INT:fullreqtime}\" device=\"%{INT:device}\" auth=\"%{INT:auth}\" ua=\"%{DATA:ua}\" exceptions=\"%{DATA:exceptions}\" overridecategory=\"%{INT:overridecategory}\" overridereputation=\"%{INT:overridereputation}\" category=\"%{INT:category}\" reputation=\"%{WORD:reputation}\" categoryname=\"%{DATA:categoryname}\" country=\"%{DATA:country}\" "}
}
grok {
match => {"message" => "%{SYSLOGTIMESTAMP:timestamp} %{HOSTNAME:hostname} (?<timestamp>%{YEAR}:%{MONTHNUM}:%{MONTHDAY}-%{HOUR}:%{MINUTE}:%{SECOND}) %{HOSTNAME:logsource} %{WORD:program}\[%{INT:pid}]\: id=\"%{INT:id}\" severity=\"%{WORD:severity}\" sys=\"%{WORD:sys}\" sub=\"%{WORD:sub}\" name=\"%{DATA:name}\" action=\"%{DATA:action}\" method=\"%{WORD:method}\" srcip=\"%{IPV4:source_ip}\" dstip=\"%{IPV4:destination_ip}\" user=\"%{DATA:user}\" group=\"%{DATA:group}\" ad_domain=\"%{DATA:ad_domain}\" statuscode=\"%{INT:statuscode}\" cached=\"%{INT:cached}\" profile=\"%{DATA:profile}\" filteraction=\"%{DATA:filteraction}\" size=\"%{INT:size}\" request=\"%{BASE16FLOAT:request}\" url=\"%{URI:url}\" referer=\"%{DATA:referer}\" error=\"%{DATA:error}\" authtime=\"%{INT:authtime}\" dnstime=\"%{INT:dnstime}\" cattime=\"%{INT:cattime}\" avscantime=\"%{INT:avscantime}\" fullreqtime=\"%{INT:fullreqtime}\" device=\"%{INT:device}\" auth=\"%{INT:auth}\" ua=\"%{DATA:ua}\" exceptions=\"%{DATA:exceptions}\" category=\"%{INT:category}\" reputation=\"%{WORD:reputation}\" categoryname=\"%{DATA:categoryname}\" country=\"%{DATA:country}\" "}
}
grok {
match => {"message" => "%{SYSLOGTIMESTAMP:timestamp} %{HOSTNAME:hostname} (?<timestamp>%{YEAR}:%{MONTHNUM}:%{MONTHDAY}-%{HOUR}:%{MINUTE}:%{SECOND}) %{HOSTNAME:logsource} %{WORD:program}\[%{INT:pid}]\: id=\"%{INT:id}\" severity=\"%{WORD:severity}\" sys=\"%{WORD:sys}\" sub=\"%{WORD:sub}\" name=\"%{DATA:name}\" action=\"%{DATA:action}\" method=\"%{WORD:method}\" srcip=\"%{IPV4:source_ip}\" dstip=\"%{IPV4:destination_ip}\" user=\"%{DATA:user}\" group=\"%{DATA:group}\" ad_domain=\"%{DATA:ad_domain}\" statuscode=\"%{INT:statuscode}\" cached=\"%{INT:cached}\" profile=\"%{DATA:profile}\" filteraction=\"%{DATA:filteraction}\" size=\"%{INT:size}\" request=\"%{BASE16FLOAT:request}\" url=\"%{URI:url}\" referer=\"%{DATA:referer}\" error=\"%{DATA:error}\" authtime=\"%{INT:authtime}\" dnstime=\"%{INT:dnstime}\" cattime=\"%{INT:cattime}\" avscantime=\"%{INT:avscantime}\" fullreqtime=\"%{INT:fullreqtime}\" device=\"%{INT:device}\" auth=\"%{INT:auth}\" ua=\"%{DATA:ua}\" exceptions=\"%{DATA:exceptions}\" category=\"%{INT:category}\" reputation=\"%{WORD:reputation}\" categoryname=\"%{DATA:categoryname}\" country=\"%{DATA:country}\" application=\"%{WORD:application}\" app-id=\"%{INT:app-id}\" "}
}
}
}
```

As you can see I spent sometime trying to account for each variation of log entries the firewall will produce. For the most part the data is the same but after a certain point it changes. When logstash parse the data it produce multiple data for one field. Here is a pic of the duplicate fields [screenshot from ELK](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lWdYd.jpg)

My assumption is that my grok patterns are too similar. I originally tried break_on_match => false but that produced the same duplicates.

Comment: You can put multiple pattern in the same grok filter, with the break_on_match => true, it will stop after the first match.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like @Phonolog said, since you have multiple grok filter, your message will be matched once with each filter. And if more than one filter successfully match its pattern against your message, you'll have duplicates of the field.

Instead of trying to match each possible combination of key-value pair at the end of your message, you can put the part with the key-value pairs in one field and then use the [kv filter](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-filters-kv.html) on it.

It would look like this:

```
grok {
  match => {"message" => "%{SYSLOGTIMESTAMP:timestamp} %{HOSTNAME:hostname} (?<timestamp>%{YEAR}:%{MONTHNUM}:%{MONTHDAY}-%{HOUR}:%{MINUTE}:%{SECOND}) %{HOSTNAME:logsource} %{WORD:program}\[%{INT:pid}]\: %{GREEDYDATA:kvdata}"}
}

kv {
    source => "kvdata"
    trim_value => "\""
 }
}
```

Comment: +1, kv seems like a good idea. Does it support other datatypes than strings? This might be interesting as OP is dealing with ip and mac addresses.

Comment: The `kv` filter only supports values as strings right now I believe, so you'd have to be able to anticipate which keys may exist and explicitly apply other filters to convert them into other formats.

Comment: @baudsp Thank you!!! This is exactly what I needed and its working like a charm thus far. I just added another match to account for another type of pattern but other than that your exact grok pattern worked for me. Again, thank you!!